# Copying text from textarea to another textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have two textareas (`ta1` and `ta2`). What I want is `ta2` to mimic the text in `ta1`. This is easy but I need some other functionality as well.

`ta1` has a keypress (jQuery) event which checks for certain words and replaces them. For instance if I type *something* in ta1 it will be replaced with *something else*. What I want is to store the original text typed in `ta2`, without the replacement of text.

This is easy if all the user is doing is typing characters or pressing backspace. The problem comes when a user moves the cursor to somewhere in the middle of the text and starts typing. Or when the user selects a bunch of text and deletes it and starts typing. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

---

**EDIT:** To make this clearer this is what I am using this for. I am wanting something similar to Facebooks "Whats on your mind?" feature.

So a user can type `@something` and when they select from dynamically generated dropdown list it will replace `@something` with something. So say the user types "Hello @something how are you?" then the text displayed will become "Hello something how are you?"

I still however need to keep the "Hello @something how are you?" somewhere as I have an underlying div which styles "something" to have a background color. It would obviously also need to work for things like "@firstname secondname". Hope that clears things up a little.

Comment: what is expected behavior in ta2 if user edits modified text in ta1 (e.g. the "else" in your "something else" example)?

Comment: If the user modifies the text "something else" to "something el" then ta2 should hold "something el".

Comment: then i think i'm not understanding your question correctly. you said, "What I am wanting is to store the originally typed text in ta2, without the replacement of text." does this mean that before the aforementioned edit, ta1 would have "something else" and ta2 would have "something", and then after the edit, they would both have "something el"?

Comment: Correct. Sorry I had not though of that scenario - another issue.

Comment: Thanks. Will try some more. Have a good one.

Comment: with your clarifications, problem is much easier. when user selects item from dropdown, why not have the text of the item be wrapped in a tag that you apply a style to?  so when they select "firstname secondname" from the list, they actually get "<b>firstname secondname</b>"?

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** This code dynamically updates text in *t1*, replacing tags like this: `"[b]sometext[/b]"` => `"<b>sometext</b>"` and copies `"[b]sometext[/b]"` to **t2**.

```
<?php
    if (array_key_exists("encode", $_GET) && strlen($_GET["encode"]) > 0)
    {
        $text = $_GET["encode"];
        $s = preg_replace("/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/i", "<b>\\1</b>", $text);

        echo $s;

        die;
    } else
    if (array_key_exists("decode", $_GET) && strlen($_GET["decode"]) > 0)
    {
        $text = $_GET["decode"];
        $s = preg_replace("/<b>([^<]{1,})<\/b>/i", "[b]\\1[/b]", $text);

        echo $s;

        die;
    } else
    if ((array_key_exists("decode", $_GET) && strlen($_GET["decode"]) <= 0) || (array_key_exists("encode", $_GET) && strlen($_GET["encode"]) <= 0))
    {
        echo "";

        die;
    }
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name=t1]").keyup(function() {
     $.get("index.php?", {"encode": $("[name=t1]").val()}, function(data) {
      $("[name=t1]").val(data);
     });

     $.get("index.php?", {"decode": $("[name=t1]").val()}, function(data) {
      $("[name=t2]").val(data);
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <textarea name="t1"></textarea><br /><hr /><br />
  <textarea name="t2"></textarea><br /><br />
 </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** used JQ 1.4.2.

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is a textarea which sits on top of a div. The textarea has a transparent background and the divs text is hidden. User enters: "Hello @someone how are you" textarea contains "Hello someone how are you?". Div contains "Hello <b>someone</b> how are you". Anything bold in div has background-color and so will look like it is highlighted in textarea. I need the second textarea to hole original text (with the @) so I can populate the underlying div correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I've understood nothing from this comment. Did you mean this (lets think easily & simply): when i type "hello, [b]moo[\b]" in t1 (take a look over my answer), doesn't matter what's happening in t2 (for now) while t1 text ("hello, [b]moo[/b]") changes with "hello, <b>moo/<b>". 

And when that condition described above becomes "TRUE", some other element (let's say it is t2) contains "hello, [b]moo[/b]". Am i right?

Comment: This is as simple as I can make it. When you type "hello, [b]moo[/b]" in t1 then t1 will be updated to display "Hello, moo". Then I need t2 to contain "Hello, [b]moo[/b]". The problem with the method above is that no more edits can be made as t1 now contains "Hello, moo". Any further edits will remove the [b]moo[/b] from t2.

Comment: see my answer above (i've fully updated it). seems, i got your question (AT LAST!!!) =)